# can i add Run button to Notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ as a Python editor, i need to add a (Run) hotkey to the program interface in order to execute the script directly .

I would prefer to add a Run key or button to the Notepad++ program interface if possible as I've already tried using Macro and it isn't suitable for my needs.

Comment: PyCharm community edition is free https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=pycharm&product=pycharm-ce

Comment: Thanks, I've tried Pycharm before but im still using Windows 7 and im facing problem when installing  it  even with an older version,

Comment: you probably need version 2019.3.5 which can be downloaded here: https://download.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-professional-2019.3.5.exe

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated your support , I  installed Pycharm seems fine for now,

Comment: Using the [NppExec plugin](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec), you can start Python scripts from within Notepad++  via keyboard shortcut. This is exaplained [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/easy-guild-set-up-notepad-run-python-script-windows-jane-yates/).

Comment: [Thonny](https://thonny.org) might be a light-weight alternative to develop Python scripts.